# RewriteRule django, displaying h1 text in url

Tags: python, django

Here is my article
    **urls.py**

```
app_name = 'articles'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

And my article **models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    heading_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

I can access the article by this link: www.example.com/articles/7/ but I would like the user to see  the heading text of the article in his url, for example: www.example.com/articles/how-to-do-this or to still have the heading text and the article id in the url if it's necessary: www.example.com/articles/7/how-to-do-this  . How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you want is called `slug`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

But for the ease of the process I'd suggest you use `django-autoslug` https://github.com/neithere/django-autoslug/ like that.

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Article(models.Model):
    heading_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='heading_text')
```

In this case on every save your slug will be updated automatically and checked for uniqueness.

Now, in order for that to work, you need to change your `urls.py` a little bit.

```
app_name = 'articles'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

I don't see your views, but it should be something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Article

def article(request, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'article': article
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

Comment: Did everything as you mentioned, but if I visit example.com/articles/7 I get error 404. What links should be used now?

Comment: changed from url(r'^(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'), to url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'), now it works, thank you. (The regex after <slug> was changed)

Comment: Oh yeah forgot about that. Correct.